# reports-Blank between body and footer

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have created a footer for my rdlc report and I have inserted a text box just in the bottom of the body.

When I preview, it is OK but when I print the report, I find a huge blank space between the text box and the footer content

How can I eliminate this blank space?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to have something align to the bottom of an RDLC report page. However, there is a workaround that makes it possible to replicate it, it's quite complicated though. Follow these steps:

1. Create a method that generates empty line feeds *("CarriageReturn LineFeed")*:

   ```
   public string GenerateCrLf(int Count)
   {
       string Value = "";
       for (int i = 0; i <= Count; i ++) {
           Value = Value + " " + Environment.NewLine;
        }
       return Value;
   }
   ```
2. Add a new row at the end of your Tablix with a TextBox containing the following expression: `=Code.GenerateCrLf(`**x**`- cint(CountRows("Table1")))`   replacing ***x*** by a number that represents the number of lines. The value of this number is obtained by trial and error, if the size of the table changes often, you can write another function that calculates this number based on number of rows your tablix has and the number of rows that can be displayed inside on a single page. Again, you'll have to do this with a  lot of trial and error to find the magic number but it cna be made dynamically this way.
3. Add the TextBox (or table/signature/...) below the Tablix and it will automatically be displayed below.

---

This answer was taken from [this tutorial and demonstration](http://thinkaboutit.be/2012/05/placeinbottom-in-rdlc-layout/). All credit goes to the writer, Steven Renders.

Comment: Excuse me could you tell me where can I add expression =Code.GenerateCrLf(x- cint(CountRows("Table1"))) on table? Thank you

Comment: In your table you probably have one row at the top representing the TableHeaders (titles for your columns) and a row with data. Now simply add another row at the end of the table and place the expression as value definition for the first cell of that new row. Remember to calculate the number of white lines and replace the **x** in the expression